# Search without managed property name

Tags: search, managed-property, document-id

We have a customer with a SharePoint 2013 environment for which we have checked the searchable checkbox for the Managed Property docId. To search for a specific docId they must search using the managed property name as prefix, i.e. docid:AAWXJCZ6YHYS-10-57 which they don't want to. Is there a way to let them search without the prefix?

Answer (score 2):

Once you check the Searchable checkbook and run a full crawl you should be fine. Since it is an ID with dashes word breaking may interfere with how the content it crawled, so you can also play with the Complete Matching setting.

> Complete Matching: 
>   Queries will only be matched against the exact content of the property. For example, if you have a managed property "ID" that contains the string "1-23-456#7", complete matching only returns results on the query ID:"1-23-456#7", and not on the queries ID:"1-23" or  ID:"1 23 456 7".

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a result source for just DocID and have it surface results for DocID. They would just have to select the result source before searching.